# Optimizing local storage and search

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, cookies

I have a web application built in .NET

During a session, the user has to access a dictionary value, that is populated from the database. The user makes frequent calls to it.

I want to cut down the HTTP calls and want to bring the dictionary value to the client and access it from there.

I wanted to understand what would be the best practice to store this dictionary value locally in such a way that retrieving data is very quick?

What I'm trying to really do is similar to what FaceBook does with "@", so when you write @Name, it quickly makes a search in the database and replaces the text with the link. In my case, I have a fixed set of data to search from and usually it is not beyond 10-15 name-value pairs.

I contemplated of storing values in cookies, but don't really know if there would be any storage limit and am also unaware of how quick the retrieval would be.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Will this dictionary need to update every time the user visits the site or once they visit all subsequent visits use the same dictionary?

Comment: The dictionary usually remains static. It might change rarely, like once in a month. But I would want to assume that they are static.

Answer (score 1):

If the dictionary is static then you can use `JSON.stringify` and `localStorage` to store it. This way the user only needs to load it the first time they ever visit your site. After it is stored in  `localStorage`, I would suggest loading it into a JavaScript object using `JSON.parse` each time the page is loaded to speed up searching since a JavaScript object works like a hash table.

You could then add a simple check each time the page loads to see if the dictionary needs to be refreshed.

```
var globalDictionaryHash = null;

function loadDictionary()
{
  if (localStorage.getItem("my_dict") == null)
  {
    localStorage.setItem("my_dict", JSON.stringify(myObjectFromAJAXCall));
  }

  globalDictionaryHash = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("my_dict"));
  console.log(globalDictionaryHash['key']);
}
```